# Is it possible to use the conditional operator without assigning the outcome?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core view and in it I'm trying to shrink the text shown, I could use:

```
@if (item.Details.Length < 100)
{
     <span>@item.Details</span>
}
else
{
    <span>@item.Details.Substring(0, 99) ...</span>
}
```

But then I thought I could use the conditional operator:

```
<span>@{item.Details.Length < 100 ? item.Details : item.Details.Substring(0, 99);}</span>
```

I'm guessing this doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't work:

```
@if (item.Details.Length < 100)
{
    item.Details;
}
else
{
    item.Details.Substring(0, 99);
}
```

i.e. the syntax needs to be broken into `html` and `cs` parts, but is there any syntax I can use to assign and display the variable in the one-liner using the conditional operator?

Please don't tell me that all the display logic should be done in the ViewModel. I know that might be the best option but that's not what I'm asking!

Comment: I would expect it to work if you just remove the `;` - what you've got isn't a valid *statement* but it is a valid *expression*. As ever, it would really help if you'd include the exact error message you're getting instead of making us guess.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet it doesn't compile if I exclude the `;` it tells me it's expected. When I add the `;` it gives me `Only assignment, call ... expressions can be used as a statement.`

Comment: Ah, it may be the use of `{}` that's causing the problem. How about `@(item.Details.Length < 100 ? item.Details : item.Details.Substring(0, 99))`?

Comment: I just tried that I can actually declare a string `x` in-line then pop that between the `<element>` tags - I didn't know this was possible until now

Comment: Ah, that's it! Using `()` instead of `{}` - worked like a charm. I knew I'd done this before! The `()` are evaluating the expression whereas the {} is more of a code-block?

Comment: Okay, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're trying to use a conditional ?: expression as a statement - but it's not a statement expression. However, it *is* a valid expression in itself. So you need to:

- Remove `;` which is only valid after a statement
- Change the `{}` (used for a block body) to `()` (used to tell Razor how much text is the expression)

```html
<span>@(item.Details.Length < 100 ? item.Details : item.Details.Substring(0, 99))</span>
```

Note that in C# 8, you can use the range operator for more brevity:

```html
<span>@(item.Details.Length < 100 ? item.Details : item.Details[..99])</span>
```